# Backprop to calculate mean and standard deviation in batch normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, batch-normalization

On page 310 of the Deep Learning book by Ian Goodfellow (Page 310 can be viewed here for better context: https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html ), it is mentioned that one crucial point about batch norm is that:

> ... Crucially, we back-propagate through
> these operations for computing the mean and the standard deviation, and for
> applying them to normalize
> H
> . This means that the gradient will never propose
> an operation that acts simply to increase the standard deviation or mean of [the layer] `h_i`
> ; the normalization operations remove the eﬀect of such an action and zero
> out its component in the gradient

The equations:

[image]

I do not understand why is it *crucial* that we backprop through these calculations and how that helps in setting the mathematical intuition to batch norm, as mentioned in the book.

Can someone help me connect the dots here?